# Training Completed Every 24 months check

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out the correct query needed to check if the user completed a specific training type every 24 months since he started his employment. The user needs to complete a certain training every 24 months.

```
    SELECT userid, completiondate 
      FROM trainingevent 
INNER JOIN emplpoyment e 
        ON e.userid = trainingevent.userid
     WHERE userid = 1007 
       AND trainingtype = 5
```

CASE 1: Let's say the employment start date is 5/15/2017 then the user should show a completion date if that training type was completed anytime between 5/15/2017 and 5/15/2019.

CASE 2: Let's say the employment start date is 5/15/2017 then the user should show a completion date if that training type was completed anytime between 5/15/2019 and 5/15/2021.

the expected result should be: if the user completed the training

```
1007 5/15/2018
```

the expected result should be: if the user did not completed the training

```
1007 NULL
```

Comment: So why doesn't what you have work as you expect?

Comment: @Larnu I'm still missing another condition to check if there's training with completion date 24 months from the employment start date

Comment: so you just want to null the date when it wasn't within 24 months? `select userid , case when datediff(month,completiondate, getdate()) < 25 then completiondate else null end as completiondate from trainingevent ...`

Comment: You could try something like `<snip> ... WHERE DATEADD(month, -24, GETDATE()) > completiondate`

Comment: @Larnu I updated the question with two cases

Comment: You don't care about employment start date, just that they completed the training some time in the last 24 months. Which is why scsimon's solution will work for you.

Comment: @scsimon I updated the question with two cases

Comment: @FarisAhmed my comment would do that.

Comment: @EricBrandt I do care about the employment date. see the two cases I just added

Comment: You really, really don't. Think about an employee who's been with the company for 49 months....

Comment: Are anniversaries preserved (i.e. potentially there can be more than 24 months between any two training sessions), or does the employee simply have to complete training no later than 24 months after the previous completion?

Comment: In fact, scrutinising your cases more closely, I think I've answered my own question: anniversaries are preserved. In other words, there are sequential periods of 24 months, anchored to the employment start date. Somewhere in each of these periods, a training course must have occurred. There can be potentially up to 48 months between two episodes of training, if the training in the first period is near the beginning of the period, and the training in the next is near the end of the period.

Answer (score 1):

I think this needs some aggregation as well, as I *think* the employee might do the training more than once from the OP's description. So perhaps something like this?

```
SELECT e.userid,
       MAX(CASE WHEN te.completiondate > DATEADD(MONTH, -24, GETDATE()) THEN te.completiondate END)
FROM dbo.employment e
     LEFT JOIN dbo.trainingevent te ON e.userid = te.userid
                                   AND te.trainingtype = 5
WHERE e.userid = 1007
GROUP BY e.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only care about training dates completed in the last 24 months.  This is a good use-case for `apply`:

```
SELECT e.userid, te.completiondate
FROM dbo.employment e OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) MAX(te.completiondate) as completiondate
      FROM dbo.trainingevent te 
      WHERE e.userid = te.userid AND
            te.trainingtype = 5 AND
            te.completiondate > DATEADD(MONTH, -24, GETDATE())
     ) te
WHERE e.userid = 1007
GROUP BY e.userid;
```

Comment: Not so Gordon. He states that the query must check that training has been completed in *every* 24 month period since the start of employment, and without reference to the employment start date, it cannot be determined in which period any training falls. I've also put a comment on his question suggesting that the anniversary of each period is preserved, and there can potentially be more than 24 months between instances - I can think of two cases (here in the UK) which follow this logic: MOTs (periodic vehicle tests) and Driver CPCs (a type of driving entitlement for professional drivers).